# How do I save a CSS class in localstorage?

Tags: javascript, css, local-storage, save

I have an HTML page with a lot of boxes and every box I click I want to apply a new CSS class that changes its background color and save the progress.
I'm trying to save this new CSS class in localstorage but i'm doing something wrong. Could someone help me?

the JS code is:

```
let box = document.querySelector(".box");
let box_1 = document.querySelector(".box-1");
let box_2 = document.querySelector(".box-2");
const next = document.querySelector(".next");


document.onload=(function(){
  var activestate = localStorage.getItem('activestate');  
    if(activestate !== ''){       
        box.classList.add('active');
     };
});

box_1.addEventListener('click', function(){
    box_1.classList.add('active');
    box_2.classList.remove('disabled-link');
    localStorage.setItem('activestate', 'active');   
});

box_2.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if (box_1.classList.contains('active')) {
        box_2.classList.add('active');
        localStorage.setItem('activestate', 'active'); 
        next.style.display = "block";
    };
});
```

here's the full code in Codepen: https://codepen.io/giuse187/pen/zYLrdMe

Comment: Please define "_doing something wrong_". What you expect your code to do, and what it does instead?

Comment: As far as I see, `onload`, there's nothing to be added in the `localStorage`. But, `onclick`, the values are added in the `localStorage`.

Comment: regarding your code, you put in localstorage an item 'activestate' with the value 'acitve' (string). You get on load the value of the item 'activestate' which is a string 'active'. What do you intend to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace "document.onload" with "window.addEventListener"

`

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var activestate = localStorage.getItem('activestate');  
  if(activestate !== null && activestate !== '') {       
    box.classList.add('active');
  }
});
```

`

Comment: Use snippet only if you have all set up of a working demo. Right now your snippet is not working because you only used the script.

Comment: Thankyou so much, "window.addEventListener('load', function() { " solved all my problems!

Answer (score 0):

Your `onload` function is not correct that's why you are not getting the results.

Use window.load instead-

```
window.onload = () => {
  // YOUR CODE
};
```

I would suggest using the `onload` event on your body element which is the recommended way to handle things on page load-

```
<body onload="checkStorage()">....your elements...</body>
```

And on Js side, do like this-

```
function checkStorage() {
  var activestate = localStorage.getItem('activestate'); 
  if(activestate !== ''){       
   box.classList.add('active');
  };
}
```